# How to add a label of a point to a polygon

Tags: qgis, polygon, point-in-polygon

i have several polygons with in each polygon a point with a label (number).

I want to add the label in the polygon to the attribute-table of the polygon it belongs to.

Comment: Try using Vector > Data Management Tools > Join attributes by location.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Spatial Join](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000q000000)  in arcgis

also see [spatial join in qgis](http://maps.cga.harvard.edu/qgis/wkshop/join_spatial.php)